# Status bar doesn't show up in Flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

Flutter app is not showing the status bar(PFA). I don't want a full-screen view of my app.
Is there any way to resolve this issue.

[image]

main.dart

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
// This widget is the root of your application.
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return MaterialApp(
  title: '',
  theme: ThemeData(
    primarySwatch: Colors.purple,
    fontFamily: 'FIRSNEUE'
  ),
 
 home: SplashScreenFirst(),

  routes: <String, WidgetBuilder> {
    '/dashboard': (BuildContext context) => Dashboard(title: ''),
    '/login': (BuildContext context) =>  Login(),
    '/service-dashboard': (BuildContext context) => Service(),
    '/service-exists': (BuildContext context) => ServiceExists(),
    '/partnerOffers' : (BuildContext context) => Partner(),
    '/visitorRequest' : (BuildContext context) => VisitorRequest(),
    '/vistorRequestSuccess' : (BuildContext context) => VisitorRequestSuccess(),
    '/mealPlan' : (BuildContext context) => MealPlan()
  },
  
);
}
}
```

login.dart

```
return Scaffold(
    key: _scaffoldKey,
    body: ListView(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
        children: <Widget>[
          Center(
            child: Container(
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 0, 10, 0),
                      width: double.infinity,
                      height: 720,
                      child: Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          SizedBox(height: 65.0),
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 43.0,
                            width: 136,
                            child: Image.asset(
                              "images/logo.png",
                              fit: BoxFit.cover,
                            ),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(height: 45.0),
                          Text(
                            'Please login to continue',
                            style: TextStyle(
                                color: Color(0xffB13F8F),
                                fontSize: 16,
                                letterSpacing: 0.15),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(height: 145.0),
                          emailField,
                          _error
                              ? _phoneController.text.length > 0
                                  ? (SizedBox(
                                      height: 1,
                                    ))
                                  : Container(
                                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
                                      child: Text(
                                        'Something went wrong. Please try again',
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                            color: Colors.redAccent,
                                            fontSize: 16),
                                      ),
                                    )
                              : (SizedBox(
                                  height: 1,
                                )),
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 104.0,
                          ),
                          _isLoading
                              ? Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())
                              : _isDisabled
                                  ? loginButtonDisabled
                                  : loginButon,
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 15.0,
                          ),
                        ],
                      ))
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ]));
 }
```

Comment: please add your code

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Please check the two files created when creating the flutter project and comment out or delete.

- ./ios/Runner/Info.plist

```
<key>UIMainStoryboardFile</key>
<string>Main</string>
<key>UIStatusBarHidden</key>                <- <here>
<true/>                                     <- <here>
<key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
```

- ./android/app/src/main/res/values/styles.xml

```
<style name="NormalTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>  <- <here>
```

Answer (score 4):

**For IOS:**
Please check the two files created when creating the flutter project and update the value from false to true.

./ios/Runner/Info.plist

```
<key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
<false/> -> Change to true
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply wrap your scaffold with **SafeArea** widget,
and your top edge won't touch status bar

Answer (score 0):

only Add two line in android -> app -> src -> main -> res -> values -> styles.xml

```
<item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
<item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

A Flutter-only solution could be wrapping your scaffold in the following code:

```
    AnnotatedRegion<SystemUiOverlayStyle>(
      value: SystemUiOverlayStyle.dark,
      child: Scaffold(
        ...
      )
```

This would set your status bar items to black color. If you want your app dependant on the device's theme you should take into account the Theme.of(context).brightness when setting the dark or light setting on the AnnotatedRegion.